# Using xsl:if doesn't include closing tag

Tags: html, xslt, umbraco

Trying to use the following code to insert a google ad inside of a blog roll

```
<xsl:if test="position() = 3">
    <object data="/frontpage_blogroll_center_top_728x90" 
            width="735" 
            height="95"  ></object>
</xsl:if>
```

For some reason the closing tag `</object>` doesn't get rendered in the HTML and causes error. Is there anyway to resolve this?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and for three complete solutions. :)

Comment: I need to keep the test="position() =  3" . I am using it in a blog roll and want to insert it in the middle of one.

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answers or do you still have a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no difference (except lexical) in XML between**:

```
<object></object>
```

and

```
<object/>
```

These represent exactly the same XML element, and different XSLT processors are free whichever of the two representations above they choose.

**If the long form of the element is really needed in HTML, this can be achieved by either**:

- Using `<xsl:output method="xhtml"/>` . The `xhtml` method is only available in XSLT 2.0.
- Using `<xsl:output method="html"/>` . The result of the XSLT transformation will be an HTML document (not XML).
- Using a trick, like:

  ```
  <object data="/frontpage_blogroll_center_top_728x90" width="735" height="95"  >
    <xsl:value-of select="$vsomeVar"/>
  </object>
  ```

where `$vsomeVar` has no value and will not cause anything to be output, but will trick the XSLT processor into thinking something *was* output and thus outputting the long form of the element.

Comment: Where can I use it with <xsl:if test="position() = 3"> I want to use it with a blogroll so that it inserts after position 3

Comment: The `$vsomeVar` trick doesn't always work. Also, bear in mind it doesn't matter what the XSLT does if the output is an object representing an XML DOM rather than textual XML source; it's whatever serializes the XML DOM to a string that makes the difference. NB: This is a general observation, and might not apply to this question.

Comment: @Flynn1179: In my practice this has worked so far. I have seen Michael Kay also recommend this trick.

Comment: @BlindingDawn: Just place the code in the body of your `<xsl:if>`

Comment: I don't know where the $vsomeVar idea comes from. It certainly won't have any effect in Saxon. I think the answer to this question is: use the right output method, and make sure the serialization is done by the XSLT processor, not by some subsequent process.

Comment: @Dimitre: Would `<xsl:value-of select="''" />` work rather than using a variable, generally? It does with .NET's `XslCompiledTransform`. Anyway, the point I was making is that any XSLT processor that outputs as a DOM rather than textual XML source doesn't have any control over the later serialization of the XML DOM to a string, and whether or not this trick is used will have no influence over that process.

Comment: @Dimitre: I also note that some processors don't use the self closing form for empty elements when there is some posible (but actually absent) content template.

Comment: Do note that niether XSLT 1.0 nor XSLT 2.0 specifications explicitly say anything about this behavior, but one can extrapolate it from *"The `html` output method should not output an end-tag for empty elements"*: if it must respect the DTD declaration for empty elements, it should also respect it for non empty elements.

Comment: @Michael-Kay, @Alejandro, @Flynn1179: Your statements are correct. The safe and proven way is (e.g. with .NET's XslCompiledTransform) to explicitly provide your own writer that would abide by whatever rules you want to establish. However this is time-consuming and requires some expertise that may put the bar too high for some people. This is why I mentioned "the  trick", which may or may not work in a specific environment, but I know that it definitely works in *some* environments.

Comment: Generally, with Umbraco I simply use the <xsl:value-of select="''" /> method Flynn1179 mentioned above.  Final code: <object data="/frontpage_blogroll_center_top_728x90" 
            width="735" 
            height="95"  ><xsl:value-of select="''" /></object>

Comment: @BeaverProj: Good, but do remember that this behavior, as well as the trick mentioned by @Alejandro above, is not only XSLT-processor-specific, but even might suddenly change with the next version of the *same* XSLT processor.

Answer (score 2):

Use `html` output method.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:if test="true()">
            <object data="/frontpage_blogroll_center_top_728x90"
                    width="735"
                    height="95"  ></object>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<object height="95" 
        width="735" 
        data="/frontpage_blogroll_center_top_728x90"></object>
```

Tested with MSXSL, Xalan, Oracle, Saxon, Altova, XQSharp.

Comment: +1. Your answer is also correct and you have spent time and effort writing it.