# Autoclose xml tag during xslt transformation

Tags: xslt

I have :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="idsProduct" value="{@id}" 
       id="form_checkbox_product_{@id}">
    <xsl:if test="$x=$y">
        <xsl:attribute name="checked" >checked</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</input>
```

and I get :

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="idsProduct" value="26294"
         id="form_checkbox_product_26294" checked="checked"></input>
```

I want an input tag like :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="idsProduct" value="26294" 
       id="form_checkbox_product_26294" checked="checked" />
```

my xsl output is :

```
 <xsl:output 
      omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
      method="xml"
      encoding="utf-8"
      indent="no" />
```

How can I autoclose this tag?

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using?  Xalan, MSXML, .Net, libxslt?

Comment: ...and why exactly do you need this?  In XML, <input></input> is actually equivalent to <input />.  If you need it for HTML, then you should use `method="html"` in your `<xsl:output />` tag.

Comment: @Martijn for w3c validation "xhtml" and no html it's why the output is xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to this question (although your problem is the direct inverse):

[Using xsl:if doesn't include closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964016/using-xslif-doesnt-include-closing-tag/4964111#4964111)

There's discussion of a 'trick' here that causes the longer form of a closed element to be used, which you appear to be inadvertently using here, in a slightly different form. I suspect your problem is because you're asking the xslt to output directly to text. Outputting to an xml document first, and then serializing that should solve your problem.

Here's an extension method I used for transforming to an `XmlDocument` rather than a string, which you can then simply read the `.OuterXml` property of if you want the string equivalent; because XSLT isn't doing the outputting to text, it should treat the closed tags correctly.

```
    public static XmlDocument Transform(this XmlDocument input, XslCompiledTransform xslt)
    {
        XmlDocument outDoc = new XmlDocument(input.CreateNavigator().NameTable);
        using (XmlWriter xr = outDoc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        {
            xslt.Transform(input, xr);
        }

        return outDoc;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing *all* whitespace from between the tags:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="idsProduct" value="{@id}" id="form_checkbox_product_{@id}"><xsl:if test="$x=$y"><xsl:attribute name="checked" >checked</xsl:attribute></xsl:if></input>
```

Does that work?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to work. Whitespace in an XSLT stylesheet is ignored unless it appears in xsl:text.

Comment: @Flynn1179: [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip) is very clear on this: *For stylesheets, the set of whitespace-preserving element names consists of just `xsl:text`.*

Comment: @Flynn1179: literal result elements like your `foo` **are in the stylesheet** and the striping whitespace only text nodes rules for stylesheets do apply to them.

Comment: @Flynn1179: And by some XSLT processor wich ones do you mean? An stylesheet with only this rule `<xsl:template match="/">
  <foo>
   <xsl:element name="bar"/>
  </foo>
 </xsl:template>` will output `<foo><bar/></foo>` in Xalan, Oracle, Saxon, Altova, XQSharp and MSXSL 3/4...