How to prevent end node name from being written when parsing xml with MSXML6
Apologies for the unclear title but I'm unsure of the correct terminology.
Allow me to clarify:
My starting XML
<osmChange>
    <way id="304298875">
      <nd ref="3088293757"/>
      <tag k="name" v="Tizard Place"/>
    </way>
    <way id="305295788">
      <nd ref="12232709336"/>
      <nd ref="3099014747"/>
      <tag k="building" v="train_station"/>
    </way>
</osmChange>

I'm loading this xslt/xpath into MSXML6 using transformNode command to filter out any nd nodes.
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="nd"/> 

The data returned is valid except it reformats the remaining tag nodes adding it's end name:
<way id="305295788">    
<tag k="building" v="train_station">
</tag>
</way>

Is there a way to amend the XSLT to prevent this so it appears as:
<way id="305295788">
<tag k="building" v="train_station"/>
</way>

Or is there even a better way to achieve my goal?

The result I get trying your code using the MSXML 6 processor at https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/ is: <tag k="building" v="train_station"></tag> which is very different from the result you show: <tag k="building" v="train_station">&#10;</tag>.  Assuming that's a mistake on your part, this seems to be a serialization issue. Possibly a matter of configuring the processor?

See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5041444/17153010.

I don't think that there is a way to achieve this, because both versions are semantically identical. Sorry. From the technical perspective, there is no difference between <a attr="a"></a> and <a attr="a" />. Both contain no child-nodes.
